что не так с import sass в react
Sass в react работает нормально, но как я понял это пока что, вскоре наверное не будет, ругается на правильность импортов.
раньше изучал react, так не ругался, сейчас же начал.
подскажите как мне правильно все сделать, чтобы не было предупреждений с импортами, так как очень удобно работать с sass.

